# Method 'Save As of Object'_Workbook Failed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with my excel `macro` "saving as" my sheet as a `PDF` as well as saving it in the current `CSV` format

This is the line that is giving me issues in my debugger

```
 ChDir "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Lips\PDFs" <br>
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=".pdf", FileFormat:= _
 xlPDF
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mmm... maybe give a file proper name, not only ".pdf" extension?

Comment: it just has to be dynamic.  is there a way to reference cell A1 since it has the order ID and then add the .pdf extension to that?

Comment: filename = Cells(1, "A")&".pdf" and on the next line ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filename, FileFormat:= _ xlPDF

Comment: unfortunately still getting an error :(

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure you can save Excel file in PDF format? Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx There is no PDF format listed...

Comment: There's no xlPDF format. Use the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method of either the `Worksheet`  or `Workbook` object to publish to a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method:

```
Dim sPath as String, sFile as String
sPath = "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Lips\PDFs\" 'this last backslash is necessary
sFile = Range("A1").Value & ".pdf"
sPath = sPath & sFile

'change other parameters as needed (can also use 'ActiveSheet` for just a given sheet
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= sPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= True
```

Comment: I seem to be getting closer.  only now i'm getting the error - "Document Not Saved.  The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving"

Comment: Do you have a version of the PDF with the same name in the same file path open already? When the file already exists in the folder, but is not open, it will overwrite it by default. Also, make sure your `sPath` variable is 100% accurate (spelling, etc.).

Comment: It is not open I believe.

Comment: Hmmm ... It may be the Google Drive, as @Jason Faulker alludes to below. Try it on the C:\ drive or a network and see if it works. If so, you'll have to find out why it doesn't work on the Google Drive folder and see if there is a work around. Also, tell what sPath is before you try to save it. You can do a `debug.print sPath` right before the `ActiveWorkbook.Export... ` line.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to save a Workbook as a PDF instead of a Worksheet. To export the current sheet to PDF, you have to use an export, not a save command:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat FileName:="MyFile.pdf" Type:=xlTypePDF
```

This aside, the issue may be you are saving directly to a Google Drive. While it has Windows Explorer integration you may not be able to save to it using a standard save operation.

A quick test would be to try to do this manually. Do File > Save As and see if you can browse (via the *folder browser*) to this location and successfully save it. If Google Drive is only available as a "Place" then you may not be able to save to it directly via a macro. If this is the case, you can try [this script](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/dropbox-google-drive-to-office-2013/) to attempt to enable the functionality but I have not tried it myself and am not sure if it would resolve your problem.